# How to resolve this error 010067 while running a reclassified Raster to Polyline?

Tags: raster, line, error, error-010067

[image: how to resolve this error 010067 while running raster to polyline?]

I'm facing this error while running a reclassified Raster to Polyline in ArcGIS 10.2. Also, I've attached the input data information[image]

Comment: what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: If you don't provide information about the inputs to the tool, we can't begin to speculate what was wrong.

Comment: I've updated my question. Kindly look into it.